# how to convert a regex match to string in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I had a paragraph containing:

`<h1 class="entry-title">`**Zynga Texas Holdem Poker cards – Free Chips**`</h1>`

```
 <p><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-276" id="download" alt="DownloadNow" src="http://xyz/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/DownloadNow.gif" 
    width="357" height="111" /> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>Instructions how to use the cards:</strong></em></span></p>
```

I got the desired match in the bold using:

```
(?<="entry-title\">)(.*?)(?=(-|</h1))
```

But I do not know how to convert this match to a string in jquery.

should I use `var matched = (?<="entry-title\">)(.*?)(?=(-|</h1));`

will

```
alert(matched);
```

show the desired result?

Comment: you are using look behind here... it is not supported in javascript

Comment: I think this is javascript and as far as I know javascript doesn't support lookbehind, so how did this regex work for you ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I made a fiddle http://bootply.com/76903 can you suggest any alternative for lookback for this code sir?

Comment: Why not `$(".entry-title").text()` ? http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Hpcpp/

Comment: haha I could try that as well.. but since I prefer regex as well..

Comment: I agree with others who've said you should be using jquery instead of regexes. But you don't seem to know about capture groups, so I'll take the opportunity to educate :-) `var match = /<h1[^>]*>(.*?)(-|</h1>)/.exec(string); var title = match[1];`. The `match[1]` part means take the string that matched the 1st pair of brackets in the regex.

Comment: @DavidKnipe this method is good but it matches the entire content along with <h1> and </h1> tags.. is there a way to match inbetween them here http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6s4/

Comment: It's giving the wrong answer because you've done `alert(match);` instead of 'alert(title);`. Incidentally, I forgot to escape the `/` in the regex; it should be `/<h1[^>]*>(.*?)(-|<\/h1>)/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Hpcpp/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var matched = $(".entry-title").text();
  alert(matched);
});
```